# RTL8822BE fails to connect after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, upgrade, realtek-wireless

After upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 I haven't been able to connect to either of my wireless networks. I believe the former 8822BE driver has been rolled into rtw88 on this release, perhaps that is causing this issue? Thanks in advance for the help!

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
    RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi 
    adapter [1043:8746]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

Output of `nmcli dev wifi list` (WPA1/WPA2 are the only options in my router but I've tried disabling security completely and still wasn't able to connect)

```
IN-USE  SSID       MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        Home-4GHz  Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2 
        Home-5GHz  Infra  149   270 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e rtw`

```
[    6.017448] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    6.052668] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci msi enabled
[    6.150480] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.533224] rtw_pci 0000:03:00.0: start vif 64:6e:69:60:a6:f3 on port 0
```

Output of `dmesg` after **Activation of network connection failed** notice

```
[ 1809.956527] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6
[ 1810.467474] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 1/3)
[ 1810.575363] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 2/3)
[ 1810.683246] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 3/3)
[ 1810.786831] wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out
[ 1814.175773] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6
[ 1814.689926] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 1/3)
[ 1814.791697] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 2/3)
[ 1814.895748] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 3/3)
[ 1814.999230] wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out
[ 1818.812088] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6
[ 1819.325794] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 1/3)
[ 1819.428087] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 2/3)
[ 1819.532030] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 3/3)
[ 1819.639684] wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out
[ 1823.852542] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6
[ 1824.363464] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 1/3)
[ 1824.464505] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 2/3)
[ 1824.572516] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 3/3)
[ 1824.676257] wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out
[ 1833.894511] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6
[ 1834.419771] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 1/3)
[ 1834.521525] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 2/3)
[ 1834.625352] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 (try 3/3)
[ 1834.733077] wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out
```

Output of `sudo iw reg get`

```
global
country CA: DFS-FCC
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
(5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
(5470 - 5600 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
(5650 - 5730 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
(5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)

phy#0
country 00: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
(2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
(5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
(57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)
```

Output of `modinfo rtwpci`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtwpci.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Realtek 802.11ac wireless PCI driver
author:         Realtek Corporation
srcversion:     921C130097AC50DFC802767
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000C822sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000B822sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mac80211,rtw88
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtwpci
vermagic:       5.3.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        66:C4:C9:9C:E0:67:27:97:7F:2B:F5:9C:6D:A1:E4:A2:F8:A3:EF:B8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      16:54:EF:AB:BA:F1:95:D5:16:D3:FF:20:72:5F:13:72:62:D1:13:13:
    88:C9:86:FB:A0:03:84:61:23:C4:7A:65:91:D8:24:7A:E9:DB:A0:13:
    D7:3C:0B:CD:B6:8E:F8:95:D2:5C:D8:56:50:33:45:59:8E:A3:DC:8F:
    07:61:28:31:B4:19:BD:E8:1C:A6:36:A7:C6:96:55:BC:49:B3:09:61:
    AD:DD:DB:1F:A0:4C:FB:DA:B5:29:BC:2C:EF:20:2C:63:3E:5D:C1:0D:
    80:07:2F:BA:C8:E9:6E:7A:2B:2E:87:A5:A9:89:9D:99:DE:4D:CC:7A:
    FF:19:EC:5F:24:EE:A0:BF:61:62:02:77:65:3E:62:D0:C7:4E:4F:5B:
    F5:8E:E0:50:08:17:40:65:4A:EB:DF:5A:1D:9C:AA:BD:A0:9F:23:DB:
    9E:62:FE:46:E6:84:5D:CF:C1:97:0D:48:EE:6A:DC:6A:BD:78:9B:27:
    67:20:2D:AB:1B:DF:65:2B:2E:10:83:79:9B:D6:88:B3:A0:DE:AE:4F:
    65:F6:FC:EF:EE:E6:0D:BB:D9:94:A9:16:6E:31:D5:6C:FB:68:81:68:
    3B:2A:F1:52:2C:06:F9:5E:A6:73:ED:CA:09:27:64:90:4C:58:F8:2A:
    D1:9D:E6:D4:B1:DF:1F:19:B3:F1:DA:D1:21:4E:98:DA:C6:BC:A8:31:
    6D:63:F0:55:63:8D:18:B9:B6:E0:8A:72:8F:94:49:31:95:82:EE:5D:
    57:CD:C7:74:7F:4A:68:90:B9:E6:D6:5C:E7:3A:61:4D:27:1F:3D:7D:
    69:59:2C:77:1C:23:C1:9D:5B:B3:3F:3A:98:20:8E:17:07:61:5E:45:
    B5:5D:31:38:5C:08:57:9C:6D:4D:D0:A0:AC:CE:8E:0C:03:1C:11:A1:
    4F:2F:43:BA:41:ED:F2:24:BE:E7:7F:49:6E:7E:06:DA:C6:75:8C:31:
    85:9A:39:B7:BB:41:1F:F4:92:26:4A:49:15:50:DA:C5:07:59:BB:A2:
    A0:1B:8E:43:BA:BA:D7:23:D6:6D:8D:B6:8D:E3:D2:37:7E:1E:61:FE:
    7C:02:CF:7A:C5:12:75:CA:CD:52:76:E4:D3:05:71:CF:4E:CA:51:9A:
    84:15:C2:17:83:B7:E4:FC:04:6B:54:AA:B7:0F:3D:C4:AF:5D:3B:2E:
    76:48:CF:B2:C4:0C:85:3B:34:87:0D:45:5A:D8:8A:61:D0:22:F1:B2:
    28:B6:C5:4C:55:08:6A:74:9E:0A:5F:C6:72:7A:2A:FF:88:23:E5:3C:
    CC:82:CC:DF:11:B0:C2:4B:ED:2F:5D:43:79:C0:ED:A2:88:97:D0:B9:
    AE:77:89:4E:F3:62:AC:09:EF:1D:0C:C7
parm:           disable_msi:Set Y to disable MSI interrupt support (bool)
```

Output of `modinfo rtw88`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-20- generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw88.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Realtek 802.11ac wireless core module
author:         Realtek Corporation
firmware:       rtw88/rtw8822b_fw.bin
firmware:       rtw88/rtw8822c_fw.bin
srcversion:     0A8E1AD14E8A75E39BF9FBB
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           rtw88
vermagic:       5.3.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        66:C4:C9:9C:E0:67:27:97:7F:2B:F5:9C:6D:A1:E4:A2:F8:A3:EF:B8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      02:9F:AC:7C:3F:D4:35:A5:B5:A8:DE:3C:7F:02:A8:4F:C6:CA:35:00:
    B0:1E:4E:9E:0A:29:77:48:F4:A3:4A:13:62:7E:46:4D:08:2D:A5:C5:
    E8:E0:F7:15:5E:EE:32:38:27:C3:25:27:21:F2:50:82:82:8F:64:04:
    36:9E:63:80:F3:C7:EE:4A:8C:CF:F7:6F:D0:4D:41:2F:7A:09:3D:24:
    8C:1F:27:DF:1D:43:9E:95:87:E3:80:6B:10:82:21:4D:4F:27:1F:6E:
    65:9D:EB:53:7A:F0:F1:ED:3D:4B:19:41:BA:2D:99:6A:6B:10:39:6A:
    29:44:DB:C1:9D:54:B7:FF:28:81:21:E5:B1:C6:00:4F:3D:D2:62:6D:
    41:40:45:25:E4:65:AE:3E:BF:99:C4:FB:61:60:C4:7A:BA:13:B2:86:
    E3:2D:D7:11:C0:A0:26:1E:8E:76:57:32:AB:E2:5E:F7:ED:8F:DC:96:
    25:97:56:12:AD:0D:54:F7:5E:F4:1B:7C:9B:DD:75:29:FD:69:34:2F:
    30:3E:F5:DC:BA:0D:03:80:2E:EB:56:C4:89:6C:96:20:7A:64:D7:78:
    4D:C9:C1:80:02:27:CF:3D:61:47:68:60:DC:9E:39:DA:FB:91:DB:13:
    DF:F1:0B:BF:5A:92:5A:A4:EC:14:F4:EB:94:C9:28:1C:4C:E3:06:FF:
    1F:E2:70:D5:F5:06:30:01:73:5F:FC:5F:48:7E:51:05:4F:A6:E5:88:
    0C:F5:92:62:6D:F1:0C:59:40:DC:44:6B:BE:8B:C2:34:1B:7B:EC:D3:
    FF:0B:41:DA:29:FD:4B:BD:30:E0:0F:1D:7E:92:BA:91:3B:AE:C8:7B:
    09:01:7D:0B:CA:90:7D:66:56:7D:E8:55:49:F0:6A:C3:6C:33:00:FF:
    2B:0D:96:86:EB:D4:3B:83:C3:77:BA:41:7E:E6:3E:07:F8:8E:10:78:
    FF:C7:32:21:1A:1A:C8:44:72:52:2C:75:5F:7D:64:72:F1:5A:DE:1C:
    AD:33:D7:F6:01:34:42:9F:59:B0:C3:B2:24:38:88:9B:99:11:E4:A3:
    A3:8E:53:53:B7:82:B6:81:FA:B8:45:40:70:D2:91:5D:AD:50:CA:F7:
    F7:5D:EE:96:67:5E:7F:F2:EE:8F:F3:F9:EA:4C:1A:A3:19:77:12:C4:
    6B:C6:64:B0:F5:79:72:38:E4:A2:A5:B9:D6:2D:5C:94:14:E5:47:04:
    EB:4B:6F:4C:BB:6D:82:61:83:C5:DC:63:B5:CB:E5:48:A6:AF:B2:9D:
    FE:B5:4D:99:AD:AE:D3:F8:77:71:97:1B:9E:6D:32:BB:A5:38:0B:64:
    1E:5A:97:0A:1B:95:06:30:22:85:DE:B2
parm:           support_lps:Set Y to enable Leisure Power Save support, to turn radio off between beacons (bool)
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=24 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Try disabling WPA1 and/or TKIP encryption on the router

Comment: unfortunately I'm not able to turn off WPA1 on my D-Link DIR-822 router, but I disabled security completely and still got the same `wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out` message

Comment: Edit to include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: Thanks for your time on this Jeremy, edited with output from `iwconfig`.

Comment: Try `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and reboot

Comment: I ran that command (there was no output) but still getting the same:

` wlp3s0: authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 timed out, wlp3s0: aborting authentication with 10:62:eb:98:c2:f6 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)`